# Cannot start Qt Creator after updating to 15.04

Tags: application-development, 15.04, qt, ubuntu-sdk

My Qt Creator (from ubuntu-sdk) won't start after updating to 15.04. It gives this dialog after the window has opened:

[image]

```
[3]+  Segmentation fault      (core dumped) qtcreator
```

Also I don't understand the console prints:

```
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] attached to process.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] checking environment variable     PIPELIGHT_SILVERLIGHT5_1_CONFIG.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] searching for config file pipelight-silverlight5.1.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/home/xxx/.config/pipelight-silverlight5.1'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/etc/pipelight-silverlight5.1'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/usr/share/pipelight/configs/pipelight-silverlight5.1'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] sandbox not found or not installed!
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] using wine prefix directory /home/xxx/.wine-pipelight.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] checking plugin installation - this might take some time.
[install-dependency] wine-silverlight5.1-installer is already installed in '/home/xxx/.wine-pipelight'.
[install-dependency] wine-mpg2splt-installer is already installed in '/home/xxx/.wine-pipelight'.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] embedded mode         is on.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] windowless mode       is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] linux windowless mode is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] force SetWindow       is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] window class hook     is on.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] strict draw ordering  is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] replaced API function CreateWindowExA.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] replaced API function CreateWindowExW.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] replaced API function TrackPopupMenuEx.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] replaced API function TrackPopupMenu.
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x7422a7, 0x7e0120, {aa087e0e-    0b35-4e28-8f3a-440c3f51eef1}, 1, 0x6cf628, (null), (null), 0x7e0120): stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {aa087e0e-0b35-4e28-8f3a-440c3f51eef1}
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.1] init successful!
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  182
  Current serial number in output stream:  183
```

Why does starting Qt Creator trigger some Pipelight garbage? Yes, I have installed Pipelight, but it shouldn't have anything to do with Qt Creator... right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was that suspending my PC had disabled 3D acceleration and Qt Creator didn't start...great.

As for the Pipelight stuff, I have no idea.